# GIT no such identity: id_rsa: No such file or directory

Tags: git, github

I create a repository on github and want to push my code, but got the following tips:

```
$ git push -u origin master
no such identity: id_rsa: No such file or directory
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

**But id_rsa file is exist**, I tried to add id_rsa public key into my github setting again, and github told me this public has been used.

```
$ ls
config      id_rsa      id_rsa.pub  known_hosts
```

this is my `.ssh/` folder

config file contain serval git config to different git site. All used the same public key and they could work successfully.

What I did:

```
$git init
$git add .
$git commit -m "first commit"
$git remote add [my remote git repository address]
$git push -u origin master
// ....  error message
```

---

UPDATE:

```
$ git config core.sshCommand "ssh -v"
$ git push -u origin master
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data ~/.ssh/config
debug1: ~/.ssh/config line 2: Applying options for github.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-003ebee6
debug1: no match: babeld-003ebee6
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in ~/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: id_rsa  explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-dss>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: id_rsa
no such identity: id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Run `git config core.sshCommand "ssh -v"`, and then post the new errors produced by `git push -u origin master`.

Comment: seemed you've config the private key to the wrong path. The right path would log like this "debug1: Trying private key: /Users/lpp/.ssh/id_dsa"

Comment: @Kevin Thank you for your answer, I edited my config file at `~/.ssh/config`, and edit `IdentityFile id_rsa` to `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa` and retried `git push -u origin master`, and It worked

Comment: If you are like me, maybe you were complete bone-head and forgot to run `ssh-add <options> <path/to/your/key>`

Comment: @Kevin, how do I revert the effect of `git config core.sshCommand "ssh -v"` after I fixed the problem?

Comment: @Bill just execute `git config core.sshCommand "ssh"`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
debug1: Will attempt key: id_rsa  explicit
...
debug1: Trying private key: id_rsa
no such identity: id_rsa: No such file or directory
```

You've configured the wrong private key path. Try configure it like this.

```
Host github.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: Configure where? Which config file?

Comment: @CGFoX ~/.ssh/config

Answer (score 12):

For 2 years, **IdentityFile id_rsa** worked for me. Today, it accepts only an absolute path as in **IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa**. Weird thing.

Comment: For me, the problem is putting quotation mark and

IdentityFile '~/.ssh/id_rsa' 
or

IdentityFile '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa' 

The quotation mark needs to be removed, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

This is a different reason that OP was getting this error, but I started getting this error out of the blue. Turns out github was actually down. Before going down the rabbit hole of figuring out what's wrong with your ssh keys, check out https://www.githubstatus.com/ first.

First time I encountered this issue, the page said everything was operational. Took about 10 minutes for them to update their statuses, so check back in a few minutes if it says everything is functional.